# Semantic ui is not able to display 10k rows

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, semantic-ui

Full code: https://github.com/kenpeter/manga_info_react/tree/10k_row

It is built with React, Redux and Semantic UI.

Perhaps it is not supposed to display so many rows in a single page. I tried to display 10k rows in a single page from remote API. Chrome is not able to display it and sometimes it crash.

Is it a way to display as many as rows I can?

Answer (score 1):

If you only render rows in viewport, you can create tables with virtually unlimited amount of rows.

Two popular implementations:

---

React Virtualized. **Actively mainted**

https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/

---

Fixed data table (by facebook) – **No longer maintained**, unfortunately. So be ready to fork and fix things yourself in future if you go with this

https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/

---